# How to find Maclaurin Series Representation for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I am having trouble putting this into a Maclaurin series representation. I have figured out that the series = 1+$\frac{x}{2}$+$\frac{3x^2}{8}$+$\frac{5x^3}{16}$+..., but I don't know where to go from here to put it into summation form. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series

Answer (score 1):

Recall the binomial series

$$(1+x)^\alpha=\sum_{j=0}^\infty{\alpha\choose j}x^j,$$

where ${\alpha\choose j}$ is a generalized binomial coefficient. Using this we have that

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}=(1-x)^{-1/2}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty{-1/2\choose j}(-x)^j.$$

Recalling the identity

$${\alpha\choose j}=(-1)^j{j-\alpha-1\choose j}$$

we can rewrite this as

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty{j-1/2\choose j}x^j.$$

If you want to rewrite this further I'll leave it up to you.